# Jagged lines when increasing line width in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

I have a curved multipart line that when the line width is increased the edges become jagged. I'd like the line to be smooth if possible. I am using QGIS 2.19 Las Palmas. Is there any wat I can do this?

[image: Jagged line example]

Apologies for my lack of correct terminology - I am new to QGIS.

Comment: I think this comes from beiing a multipart line. Can you join the line parts to get a single line? You may need to sort the line parts for that. Also, you can change the end cap style of the line to be rounded.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is to do with cap style.

From the layer symbology, choose a "Round" Cap style. That should look as intended:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the linestring itself is very jagged. You could try simplifying the layer using either
1. The "Simplify geometries" tool in the processing toolbox
or
2. Make your layer editable, and then use the interactive "Simplify feature" tool from the Advanced Digitizing toolbar.